# What kind of fuzzer can i use?

Tags: vulnerability-analysis

I studied reverse engineering for 6 months.
And I wanna discover Adobe Reader vulnerability for bughunting.
But i have lack knowlege of this branch. Anyone help me plz?
My question is what kind of fuzzer can i use to fuzzing Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work like that.
As you might know, bugs are worth money. The main reason for tgis is at it requires both skill and time to find these bugs.

Clearly you want to learn this skill, so in the future you might be able to do this.

So, you can't just point a fuzzer at something and find bugs in A-software. You either need to write your own, statebased fuzzer or find bugs by reverse engineering.

I myself am a huge fan of the latter.
Read the docs on how it should work. Reverse a complex part (complex = programmer bugs) and audit the code.

When starting out, start with finding bugs in old software. That you know contains bugs.

Happy bug hunting!!

Edit: Read [Fuzzing Adobe Reader - Exploit Development](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4374/fuzzing-adobe-reader-exploit-development) Joxean Koret posted a great comment there.